# Linking torrents of both Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, utorrent, qbittorrent

I am running Ubuntu and Windows 10 in dual boot config. I use qbitorrent on both. As suggested by others, I set up the same save location of both the qbitorrent. The only problem now is that of I/O error (Read - only). If I start a download in Ubuntu and switch to Windows The I/O error appears and vice-versa.
I am not able to get around with this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use version of qBittorrent lower than 4.1.0 try to update both Linux and Windows clients. Run "force recheck" after update on torrents causing error.

If this solution din't work for you, try to check the owner of the torrent files. I guess that your storage filesystem is NTFS. Each operating system can set their own user as the owner of the files and this can lead to error.

The other option is to use other clients such as Transmission or Deluge they can work fine and also very well designed and Open Source.

Comment: I disabled the hiberfile system of Windows to access files of /media. This removes the read-only error. But now i am getting permission denied error. Also, how to check the owner of files? Pretty new to dual booting.

Comment: What version of qBittorrent are you using? Did you tried to check the torrent files owner or "force recheck" option?

Comment: Version is 4.0.3. I think the problem is that the I do not have the permission now. The owner of these folders is root. How do give the permission back to me? The filesystem Is NTFS.

Comment: Permissions related errors are fixed in version 4.1.0, so please update if you can. To change permissions you can run `sudo chown -R <username> <location>` in terminal.

Comment: Updated qbittorrent to 4.1.1. Now i have the permissions but still having the I/O error - Permission denied.

Comment: Please make sure you updated both Linux and Windows versions. Have you tried my previous advises about using `chown` and `force recheck`? You need to `force recheck` on problematic torrents to eliminate the problem even after update. It will not disappear without this action. Also you can provide more information about the error to help me understand the context. Windows and Linux versions and screenshots of errors will be also very useful.